# Average Value on Date Time per second SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
oDateTime              Value
----------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00    10
2017-01-01 00:00:01    20
2017-01-01 00:00:02    10
2017-01-01 00:00:03    10
ff.
```

The row data is per second on each date. I want to have the following result:

```
oDateTime              Value
----------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 01:00:00    10
```

So it's the hourly average for each date.
Any idea how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, oDateTime), 0)` will round any DATETIME value, down to the hour.  This enables you to keep the DateHour value as a single column.

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, oDateTime), 0),
  SUM(value) / 60.0,
  AVG(value)
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, oDateTime), 0)
```

***EDIT***: Less repetition, but slightly longer...

```
SELECT
  rounded.DateHour,
  SUM(value) / 60.0,
  AVG(value)
FROM
  yourTable
CROSS APPLY
  (VALUES(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, oDateTime), 0))) AS rounded(dateHour)
GROUP BY
  rounded.DateHour
```

Comment: the result for `dateadd(hour, 0,` .... is `4708-01-17 00:00:00.000`, the time is not display.

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating by the date and hour:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, oDateTime, 112) AS date,
    DATEPART(hour, oDateTime) AS hour,
    AVG(Value) AS Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(varchar, oDateTime, 112),
    DATEPART(hour, oDateTime);
```

Comment: convert(varchar, oDateTime, 112) ??? Am I right? The result is different with the format that I need

Comment: @MatBailie, what do you meant?